# Are Asymptote questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked a question about Asymptote which was closed as off topic.

[Asymptote: convert triple to array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111998/asymptote-convert-triple-to-array)

I believe it fits within the scope of the site in much the same way a pure `metapost` question would.  There have been both pure `metapost` and pure `asymptote` questions asked and answered, none of which were closed as off topic.  Examples being

[Commutative diagrams using MetaPost or Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/commutative-diagrams-using-metapost-or-asymptote)

[How to cut a surface at the intersection with another surface in Asymptote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87009/how-to-cut-a-surface-at-the-intersection-with-another-surface-in-asymptote)

[How to draw dash-dotted curves using MetaPost?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94830/how-to-draw-dash-dotted-curves-using-metapost)

(et. al.)

Obviously, just because it has happened before does not mean it should happen again, so I don't take the existence of the above questions to prove anything.  However, each is a question about a graphic tool that:

1. is compatible with LaTeX, and
2. which (barring `luamplib`) require an external program to compile, and
3. do not contain a trivial document wrapper (i.e. are questions purely about the tool)

I don't *particularly* care one way or another, but do feel that there should be consistency with respect to how these questions are treated.

Comment: I think it's a hasty decision plus the new review system in effect. I don't see anything wrong about it.

Comment: Some observations(Off-topic): Asymptote syntax emulates C++ and is not similar to tex/latex, probably including latex preamble(full mwe) will attract wider audience which was not there in [revision 1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/111998/1) of Q. Also note there are less heavy asymptote users here.

Comment: @texenthusiast I accept that, and including the `tex` part would have been a more inclusive way to ask the question and if it needs to be included to make an `asymptote` question on topic, then I'll simply include it.  That said, the `TeX` wrapper adds code that is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: @ScottH. Agree, many(non-asy) start executing from TeX aware editors instead of commandline `asy filename.asy` (missing in Q) and in somewhat as a larger goal to bring awareness and help wider audience thru Q & A. Remember Q &A have lot of by-products including the product(green answer). A little more effort to benefit all. Anyway no worries.

Comment: I hope so! (that asymptote questions are on topic)